# Most idiomatic way to convert a Float value to a string without a decimal point in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, math, floating-point

I'd like to convert a `Float` value to a `String`, but without a decimal point.  For example, for the following code:

```
fun toDecimalString(value: Float): String {
     // TODO
}

fun main() {
    println("Result: ${toDecimalString(1.0f)}") 
    println("Result: ${toDecimalString(1.999999f)}")
    println("Result: ${toDecimalString(20.5f)}")
}
```

I'd like the expected output to be:

```
1
1
20
```

Comment: What do you mean by the "best" way?

Comment: value.toString().substringBefore(".")

Comment: > What do you mean by the "best" way?

Best way in Kotlin

Comment: Best for code clarity, code conciseness, memory use, or execution speed, etc? We don't know know what the goal is, so the meaning of "best" is ambiguous. Usually code clarity is the first goal, in which case I'd use `.toInt().toString()`.

Comment: Most idiomatic way to do it in Kotlin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By converting to an `Int` before turning the input to a string, all decimal point values are dropped, e.g.:

```kotlin
fun toDecimalString(value: Float): String = "${value.toInt()}"
```

Answer (score 4):

As @Tenfour04 said, the answer is to first convert to an integer, by using `.toInt()`, which only leaves the digits left of the decimal point, and then convert to string using `.toString()`.

`.toInt().toString()`